# Why do my Planetary Portals sometimes look different?

Tags: egg-inc

While I'm playing Egg, Inc., sometimes my Planetary Portal habs change from this:

[image: screen shot, entrance type 1]

To this:

[image: screen shot, entrance type 2]

They'll stay that way for a while, and then some time later, I'll notice the entrances to the habs are back to the first style.

What's going on here?

Answer (score -2):

If the game realises the FPS is too low then it'll change the models to a lower poly count model to help FPS.

Sorry this is a bit of a late answer but I thought I'd post an answer incase anyone else stumbles upon this question.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is not a case of LOD switching..